# Why my program returns "No review v1" instead of returning the average review for the products with reviews?(web scraping, python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

My program prints "No review v1" for the last 4 products("Chests of Drawers, LITTLE TREE Tall Accent Chest with Open Storage, Works as File Cabinet & Collection Suitable for Bedroom or Office, Oak (5-Drawer)","Modern Innovations Bedside Tray with Cup Holder & Cable Cord Insert for Use as Bunk Bed Shelf","Mantua Cottage Style Wedgewood Blue Nightstand, Perfect for Seaside and Country DÃ©cor","Step Stool Folding Aluminum RV Step Platform with Anti-slip Surface Sturdy Lightweight Maximum Load". I don't know where is the problem. And for the product "Milan SEERAT-AS-RST Adjustable Height Swivel Stool, Rust"(the first product, it returns "5 out of 5 stars" instead of "No review v1"). The url is this "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A1063306%2Ck%3Aas&keywords=as&ie=UTF8&qid=1532070774" and the problem is on the lines 40-45 with the try/except block with review. I attached the code and the csv. I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

THIS IS THE CSV

[image]

THIS IS THE PROGRAM

```html
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from lxml import html
import io

links = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_pg_1?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A1055398%2Cn%3A1063306%2Ck%3Aas&keywords=as&ie=UTF8&qid=1532070774'
 ]
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://218.50.2.102:8080',
    'https': 'http://185.93.3.123:8080'
}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server="%s"' % ';'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in proxies.items()]))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Andrei-PC\Downloads\webdriver\chromedriver.exe",
                              chrome_options=chrome_options)
header = ['Product title', 'Product price', 'Review', 'ASIN']

with open('csv/demo.csv', "w") as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)

for i in range(len(links)):
    driver.get(links[i])
    for x in range(0,23):
        product_title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@id="result_{}"]/div/div[3]/div/a'.format(x))
        title = [x.text for x in product_title]

        try:
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@id="result_{}"]/div/div[5]/div/a/span[2]'.format(x)).text
        except:
            price = 'No price v2'
            print('No price v2')

        try:
            review = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('i.a-icon-star>span.a-icon-alt')[x].get_attribute('textContent')

        except:
            review = 'No review v1'
            print('No review v1')

        try:
            asin = driver.find_element_by_id('result_{}'.format(x)).get_attribute('data-asin')

        except:
            asin = 'No asin'
            print('No asin')

        try:
            data = [title[0], price, review, asin]
        except:
            print('no items v3 ')
        with io.open('csv/demo.csv', "a", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output)
            writer.writerow(data)
    print('I solved this link %s' % (links[i]))
    print('Number of product %s' % (i + 1))
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Try to use `for product in product_title` to iterate through list of products instead of `for x in range(0, 23)`

Comment: I use for product in product_title now and for price I change to driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('span.sx-price-whole').text and for asin i changed to driver.find_element_by_tag_name('li').get_attribute('data-asin') but it gives me 56 items in csv with "No price v1" and "No review v1". I removed the for x in range(0, 23) and changed to for product in product_title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below loop:

```
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[starts-with(@id, "result_")]')
for product in products:
    title = product.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
    price = ([item.text for item in product.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a/span[contains(@class, "a-color-base")]')] + ["No price"])[0]
    review = ([item.get_attribute('textContent') for item in product.find_elements_by_css_selector('i.a-icon-star>span.a-icon-alt')] + ["No review"])[0]
    asin = product.get_attribute('data-asin') or "No asin"
    print(title, price, review, asin)
```